# Convert raw image to buffer

Tags: node.js, image, file, raspberry-pi, buffer

There is apparently no easy way to stream images in Raspberry Pi. While there are many *hacks* available, in my Raspberry Pi Zero it has some trouble keeping a decent framerate.

I suspect one of the main problems is that the [1st Google solution](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/rpi-live-streaming/) and most of them writes/reads to the SD for each image. I've got so far to read from the terminal an image without touching the SD:

```
const out = await exec(`fswebcam -r 640x480 -`);
const img = out[0];
console.log(img);
```

This gives me this on the terminal:

```
 ����JFIF``��>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), default quality
��      

 $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C
```

And many more. Previously I was doing something similar with buffers:

```
const file = fs.readFileSync(temp);
console.log(file.toString('base64'));
ctx.socket.emit('frame', { image: true, buffer: file.toString('base64') });
```

Where `file` is a Buffer and `file.toString('base64')` is a string in the form of:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD//gA8Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4wICh1c2luZyBJSkcgSlBFRyB2ODApLCBxdWFsaXR5ID0gMTAwCv ...
```

And this worked (but through the SD card). So my question is, what is the format of the first output in terminal? And how can I convert it to a Buffer or a String similar to the latter.

Comment: Looks like jpeg - JFIF stands for Jpeg File Interchange Format, which commonly referred to as JPEG.

Comment: @barny sorry yes, it is jpg. But what I mean is, is it binary? How can I convert that saved data into an usable format such as `Buffer`?

Comment: Yes it is binary. Can you use toString() on it?

Comment: Yes, but that is what I get when I do .toString(): `console.log(img.toString())` makes `����JFIF``��>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), default quality�� [...]`

Comment: Sorry meant toString('base64') - that will produce ASCII-represented data, isn't that what you were doing with your data going to/from SD? Or if not then I really don't understand what your actual problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just using the terminal through pipe to convert it to base64:

```
fswebcam -r 640x480 - | base64
```

So now my whole snippet is:

```
// Take a picture in an async way and return it as a base64 encoded string
// Props: https://scottlinux.com/2012/09/01/encode-or-decode-base64-from-the-command-line/
module.exports = async ({ resolution = '640x480', rotate = 0 } = {}) => {
  const query = `fswebcam -r ${resolution} --rotate ${rotate} - | base64`;
  const out = await exec(query, { maxBuffer: 1024 * 1024 });
  return out[0];
};
```